# Real memory usage on Linux and Private_Dirty

Tags: linux, performance, memory, process

On Linux, is using Private_Dirty value from smaps a good way to measure real process memory usage?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about Private_Dirty, I rather use Pss.

Comment: Does Pss include shared pages?

Comment: Indeed it does include proportional part of shared memory -- for more info check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps

Comment: So it seems Private_Dirty is what I need for now. Thanks @HrvojeŠpoljar